# Compiling gsoap for x64 with Visual Studio: C4302 conversion: truncation from void* to unsigned int

Tags: 64-bit, gsoap

I am trying to compile gsoap with VS 2017 for x64. There's a compiler warning because `void*` (64bit address) is casted to `unsigned int` (32bit integer). It occurs at `h = soap_hash_ptr(p)` where p is the `void*` and h is the `unsigned int`.

That looks critical - I therefore had a look into `stdsoap2.cpp` of the current gsoap version - there however `soap_hash_ptr` seems to do the same through `PtrToUlong` - I want to keep gsoap which is great - but can I still rely on - possibly yes, because the return value of `soap_hash_ptr` is used as an index for an array or vector (either `soap->mht` or `soap->pht`) - however I am not yet quite shure - can someone give me a hint? Thank you.

- IDE: VS2017
- Target: x64
- gsoap version: Approx year 2005

Comment: This seems fine to me, since `PtrToUlong` is used to convert a pointer to an int which is then taken modulo `SOAP_PTRHASH` (with `& (SOAP_PTRHASH-1)`) to index a hash table. This can't possibly go wrong. It's just hashing into a table. I suggest to change the code in stdsoap2.h to `#define soap_hash_ptr(p)        ((size_t)((PtrToUlong(p) >> 3) & (SOAP_PTRHASH - 1)))`

Answer (score 1):

The `PtrToUlong` is correctly used to truncate the pointer, as this is actually recommended by the Win64 rules for using pointers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/rules-for-using-pointers

> 2. Use the PtrToLong or PtrToUlong function to truncate pointers.
>
> If you must truncate a pointer to a 32-bit value, use the PtrToLong or
>   PtrToUlong function (defined in Basetsd.h). These functions disable
>   the pointer truncation warning for the duration of the call.

The `soap_hash_ptr` macro that you quote is used to compute an index into a hash table:

```
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(UNDER_CE)
#define soap_hash_ptr(p)        ((PtrToUlong(p) >> 3) & (SOAP_PTRHASH - 1))
#else
#define soap_hash_ptr(p)        ((size_t)(((unsigned long)(p) >> 3) & (SOAP_PTRHASH-1)))
#endif
```

This definition and its use to index a table cannot cause an issues.